# How to dynamically increase height of UITableview based on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I want to increase the height of UITableView when user scroll to top and decrease height when user scroll to down.
I have done this situation by this code

```
if scrollView == tableView {
     print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
     let height: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y+200
     let maxHeight: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height - 64
     let minHeight:CGFloat = 200
     if height < maxHeight && height > minHeight {
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.tblHeightCons.constant = height
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
          })
      }

 }
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WA3RAMmfrKQlBVOG9NaEllRTQ/view

But i don't want to move contents..

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**. It implements the effect like in videos, and disable the content moving when scrolling in range, and enable the content moving when scrolling out of range. The fast scrolling problem is also fixed:

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height - 64
    let minHeight:CGFloat = 200
    var height = self.tblHeightCons.constant + scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if height > maxHeight {
        height = maxHeight
    }
    else if height < minHeight {
        height = minHeight
    }
    else{
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    }

    self.tblHeightCons.constant = height
}
```

Comment: When we do scrolling fast its fail to reach out to a top.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, code is updated to fix "reach out" problem. Please try again.

Comment: @YunCHEN I've tried your code on a similar case i have. Once it scroll to max height, it doesn't decrease table view height

Comment: @ItaiSpector, did you bind the TableView's height constraints to the variable we change in function? Please post a new question to provide more details and leave a link here If the situation is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i have used following way to achieve this, set your dynamic height to tableview and set contentSize for scrollview in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

```
_commentsTable.frame = CGRectMake(self.commentsTable.frame.origin.x, self.commentsTable.frame.origin.y, self.commentsTable.frame.size.width,cellDynamicHeight*_commentArray.count) ;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height+kConstantHeight);
```

Comment: Please watch the video that was uploaded.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani if you want to do something like this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2anHjlVQmm_aDExLUhXYllXVEk/view?usp=sharing) use parallaxheader (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vgparallaxheader)

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically handle scrollview and tableview in accordance with tableview height.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!// tableView height constraint 
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
            }
```